# Python bool(Ellipsis) and bool(None)

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

I don't understand how are `Ellipsis` and `None` handled differently by `bool()`, when both seem to be identical in terms of the relevant attributes for truth-testing.

```
>>> bool(Ellipsis)
True
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> any([hasattr(Ellipsis, attr) for attr in ['__len__', '__bool__', '__nonzero__']])
False
>>> any([hasattr(None, attr) for attr in ['__len__', '__bool__', '__nonzero__']])
False
```

1. Is there something else I'm missing which is used for truth-testing?
2. Are there any other objects (besides `None`) which evaluate to `False` that implement neither of `__len__` or `__nonzero__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bool(x)` is `True` if `x` is an object without one of the magic methods you mentioned returning `False`. That's why `Ellipsis` evaluates to `True`.

`None` is [special-cased](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in `bool()` and makes it return `False`.

**Details:**

`bool()` uses `PyObject_IsTrue()` API function which in 2.7.2 looks like this:

```
int
PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;
    if (v == Py_True)
        return 1;
    if (v == Py_False)
        return 0;
    if (v == Py_None)
        return 0;
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_number != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_nonzero != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_nonzero)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length)(v);
    else
        return 1;
    /* if it is negative, it should be either -1 or -2 */
    return (res > 0) ? 1 : Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(res, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

Comment: +1 for obeying Obi-Wan's timeless maxim: "Read the source, Luke". See also [the python documentation on truth-value testing](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: @wim I've got Python sources on my local machine so I just search through that. I'm not using ipython so I don't know if it can search the C sources.

Comment: @srgerg Thanks. I've added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__):

> If a class defines neither **len**() nor **nonzero**(), all its
>   instances are considered true.

`None` evaluates to false because it's a built-in type that is [specified to do so](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). You did not define `__len__()` or `__nonzero__()` on `Ellipsis`, as you stated. If you want it to evaluate to false,

```
class Ellipsis(...):
  #...
  def __nonzero__(self):
      return False

  # or
  def __len__(self):
      return 0
```